# Where Debian Lenny stores initial ifconfig values?

Tags: vmware-player, debian-lenny, ifconfig

With upgrade of VMWare Player I suddenly found my Debian Lenny VM not getting IP address. Some DHCP issue maybe, I don't know. So I have to set it manually every boot in Player window, via:

```
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 192.168.175.128 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

I usually start up VM and then connect to it via SSH, so this procedure bothers me. Sure I can add it to startup script, but is there some special place to enter these values? Like, some config file or so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the values you're looking for are configured in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

See [this resource](http://library.linode.com/networking/configuring-static-ip-interfaces/#debian__amp__ubuntu) regarding static networking configuration.

Comment: Okay, will try now.